# Need a repeator/echo server between two different subnets

Tags: python, networking

I am designing an automation framework for which I need to communicate with various machines placed in different networks. The problem I am facing is that on one of my subnet there is limited access due to security reasons so I can not make request on any port except 22 (ssh). To make this happen I need a demon which will repeat my sent commands from network A (master node) to a machine on network B (slave node) using ssh (fabric). Now I want this demon to be able to echo/repeat every command master send its way to other machines on network B and send the response back to master node in network A.

I know this is really confusing but I tried to make it as clear as I could. Please if anyone knows a way I can do it in python other than writing my own program please comment. Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who are facing a similar issue. SSH Tunneling did the trick for me. As in my case firewall was blocking everything except shh so I created ssh tunnel to a machine in Network B. Which can be done by executing following command from a machine in Network A:

> ssh -D 8123 -f -C -q -N sammy@example.com

sammy is a user on example.com in Netwrok B. Now all I had to do was use SOCKS proxy to connect to localhost:8123 and route all my traffic through this connection. Below is good tutorial you can refer:

[SOCKS Tunnel](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-route-web-traffic-securely-without-a-vpn-using-a-socks-tunnel)

Answer (score 0):

You basically need a Proxy in-between the 2 subnets. You can do a small proxy stuff with python using logics which involve:

```
1. A connection between the proxy & remote server B(original target).
2. Client_in_subnet_A --> Proxy --> Server_in_subnet_B
3. Client_in_subnet_A <-- Proxy --> Server_in_subnet_B
4. Close_connection.
```

There are some ways to do so, https://gist.github.com/pomack/6194156 or https://mitmproxy.org/

Comment: Thanks Nishant for the response. But I cannot use a proxy server as I mentioned before subnet B only allows communication on port 22 (ssh) so traditional proxy server will not work, I have tried RPC but that too is not a workable solution for me.

Comment: so only SSH traffic is to be allowed to flow?

Comment: what type of traffic will be flowing?

Comment: I need to be able to connect to a REST service in network B. But the only thing that is allowed from network A to B is ssh.